# Suppose $a\in S$ and $b\in S^{\perp}$, is it true that $a+b\in S $ and $a+b \in S^{\perp}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

In my opinion, vectors in each $S$ and $S^{\perp}$ are independent, so $a+b$ shouldn't be in either  $S$ or $S^{\perp}$, is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Assuming $a,b \neq 0$:

Note that $S \cap S^{\perp}=\{ 0\}$

so if $a+b \in S,a \in S \Rightarrow b=(a+b)-a \in S$ since a subspace is closed under subtraction. But this forces $b=0$.